# When I am using SendKeys to send the date in the field and when I am running the script its pasting the date twice in that field

Tags: java, selenium

```
        package debut.Ifinca.NewOrder;
        import org.openqa.selenium.By;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

        public class NewIfincaOrder {
        public static void main(String[] args)

            {       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\\\Users\\\\COMPUTER\\\\Desktop\\\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\\\chromedriver.exe");
                WebDriver driver = new   ChromeDriver();
                driver.get("http://js-server.debutinfotech.com:3093/");

                driver.manage().window().maximize();
 //Here When I am sending this date its getting entered twice in this field.This field has Date picker format.
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='exporter_delivery_date']")).sendKeys("02/18/2020");
        }
        }
```

Comment: `input` is empty before `sendKeys`?

Comment: Is there any additional validation done on the field? There's been some complaints about SendKeys not functioning as people intend (for various reasons) but it's typically dropping characters. Is there any html5 validation on this field? Or other javacript actions?

Comment: There is No Validation On this filed. It a Normal Field with date picker functionality on it but you can also type the date manually as its optional not to pick date from picker as long as you enter the date correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the field first?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='exporter_delivery_date']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='exporter_delivery_date']")).sendKeys("02/18/2020");
```

Comment: //Select Date for Exporter
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='exporter_delivery_date']")).sendKeys("02/19/20");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='exporter_delivery_date']")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='exporter_delivery_date']")).sendKeys("02/19/2020");

Comment: Its Working With this code . First I am Entering todays date(Its entering todays date twice E.g 02/19/2020/02/19/2020) then I am clearing the field and at last I am again sending todays date and this time there is no duplicacy.